# How does blessed Champion work?

Tags: hearthstone

When I played storming stormwind the taunting minion without attack was staying next to a flag that increased his attack by 2.

After he played blessed champion on that minion it had 4 attack.

killing the flag I was assuming the attack would drop to 2, since the doubling buff added 2 attack.

But it dropped to 0. Does this mean the buff is persistent?

I'm confused about this, since this is not consistant with the way other stat buffs in hearthstone work. Or might this just have been a bug caused by the temporarily minion of the opponents buff flag?

Answer (score 3):

Blessed Champion's buff is persistent but it doubles the minion's actual attack, not the current value which can cause confusion. There was a [discussion on Reddit about this](https://pay.reddit.com/r/hearthstone/comments/2d6651/blessed_champions_behaviour_with_buffs_makes_no/) as well as on the [hearthstone forum](http://us.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/13779227960) which go into more detail.